# Why is react-native-image-picker's showImagePicker undefined in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, uiimagepickercontroller, reactjs

Currently I am running my React Native project via terminal and Atom editor. I am trying to use rect-native-image-picker from https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker and followed the instructions to install: `npm install react-native-image-picker@latest --save`

And my `dependencies` show: `"react-native-image-picker": "^0.22.8"`

Then I tried following the exact example, yet I am still getting an error on `ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {...})` when I press the button to choose an image: `Cannot read property 'showImagePicker' of undefined`

**So I `console.log(ImagePicker)` of `import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'`, which is exactly how it is implemented in the Example project from react-native-image-picker, and it logged:**

[image]

**So I cloned the Example project and also `console.log(ImagePicker)` and it showed:**

[image]

I am starting to believe that the issue is that I am not getting functions that I am supposed to get, such as `launchCamera` and `launchImageLibrary`. I can't seem to figure out why. What could I be missing or doing incorrectly?

Comment: Did you link the dependency? `rnpm link`

Comment: @DTing sorry but what's that? In the terminal, project folder? I actually used react-native-image-picker for a previous project and installed and implmented it the exact same, and it worked then and don't recall doing the `rnpm link`.

Comment: See if following the rest of the instructions for the install section fixes your problem. https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker#install

Comment: @DTing I'm wondering why it worked in my previous project by simply doing npm install, and the rest of the institutions apply to Xcode but I use a terminal and an editor for the project.

Comment: @DTing Please let me know if you had the chance to see my previous comment.

Comment: Without more information I can't say why your previous project worked without following the directions. The rest of the instructions apply to any library that has native dependencies.

Comment: @DTing Did you delete the answer? Because for some reason I don't see it anymore...

Comment: @JoKo I think I need to *actually see* the error, I can't reproduce it. Do you have time to chat?

Comment: @TylerY86 Absolutely. Been struggling with this for days.. Feel free to open up whenever you are ready.

Comment: Have you used `setInterval`, `console.log`, and `performance.now` to try to log how soon (if ever) the symbol becomes valid?

Comment: I'll try to get in contact with you next time. It's late (or early) here... If [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5291479/jo-ko) is an accurate profile of your on time, I'll sync up with you at some point. [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124606/showimagepicker-undefined-in-react-native) is a chat room I'll check.

Comment: @TylerY86 When you get a chance, please check the chatroom.

Comment: Checking it now

Comment: @TylerY86 Left a message in the chat

Comment: @TylerY86 Just checking in to see if you've seen my last comment. Please let me know.

Comment: @TylerY86 Provided screenshots in the chat

Comment: @TylerY86 Hey Tyler, Checking in again to see if you've seen the screenshots.

Comment: @JoKo I get the tags on my name in the chat via notifications by my phone, I was just busy, then went to sleep. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @TylerY86 Feel free to let me know Tyler if it's something you cannot resolve, so I can move on. No hard feelings.

Comment: Sorry, I have been contacted by a recruiter. Priorities. :(

Comment: @TylerY86 No worries. Just needed an update. Best of luck, but would you still be able to help out after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of RN and iOS do you use? If you are sure that you linked npm package with native code (`rnpm link`), you can try add to your `Info.plist` (right key -> Open as source code) between `<dict>` tags:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
```

Comment: I'm actually using Atom editor and terminal to run the application and not Xcode. How can I make sure that I have linked npm package with native code? Do I do `rnpm link` in the terminal? My React Native is `"react-native": "0.33.0"` and how can I check the iOS version?

Comment: Did you add code above to your `Info.plist`? You can check if lib is linked in xCode: click main project -> Build Phases -> expand `Link Binary With Libraries` and find `libRNImagePicker.a` - that means your lib is linked

Comment: Is there a way to see it via text editor without using xCode?

Comment: You can check it in project -> ios -> project.xcodeproj -> project.pbxproj

Comment: Can't find the `libRNImagePicker.a`. What should I do?

Comment: Did you run `react-native link` inside your project dir? And then `react-native run-ios`? As you use RN 0.33 it should be enought, if not you can check known issues: https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed

Comment: So via terminal, in my project directory, just type in `react-native link`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126359/discussion-between-jonzee-and-jo-ko).

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue. So in the documentation, the auto-linking is given but it is not linking all the dependency. You need to link some dependency manually.
Please follow this below link it will help you.
[For manually linking follow this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/HEAD/docs/Install.md)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```js
import {launchCamera, launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';


launchCamera(options, response => {
          if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
          } else if (response.error) {
            alert('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
          } else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
          } else {
            alert(response.uri)

          }
        });
```

The reason is that ImagePicker.showImagePicker is depreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but you can solved this issue thanks to :

- this tutorial showImagePicker https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/en/react-native/react-native-image-picker/ & https://github.com/dev-yakuza/react-native-image-picker-example
- (!) I'm on React Native >= 0.60 but the react-native-image-picker version is "react-native-image-picker": "2.3.1"
- To use react-native-image-picker on iOS, open ios/[project name]/Info.plist and modify it like below.

I'm not an expert but you can solved this issue thanks to :

- this tutorial showImagePicker https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/en/react-native/react-native-image-picker/ & https://github.com/dev-yakuza/react-native-image-picker-example
- (!) I'm on React Native >= 0.60 but the react-native-image-picker version is "react-native-image-picker": "2.3.1"
- To use react-native-image-picker on iOS, open ios/[project name]/Info.plist and modify it like below.

Don't hesitate to remove your nodes_modules and pod files then restart your server

Don't hesitate to remove your nodes_modules and pod files then restart your server